# Android Build problem using android library project

Tags: android, android-library, android-build

PS: I'll refer "Android Library Project" as ALP
I has a ALP let's call A, that use a ALP B.

And has a project General that use the A as Library, but Eclipse give me some build errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
MainFrame cannot be resolved to a type  BActivity.java  /General/A_src/com/ww/general       line 5  Java Problem
The import com.woodwing.mainframe cannot be resolved    BActivity.java  /General/A_src/com/ww/general   line 3  Java Problem
```

This BActivity is part of a jar on the ALP B and is used on ALP A, but adding the A as a Library of General, the compiler give that errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I should import the jars on General also.